# Tag for Hong Kong

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag [hongkong](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hongkong) is a bit ugly. Could it please be renamed [hong-kong](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hong-kong)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good call, given that the two word version has been official since 1926, it probably makes more sense to use it as the official one over the archaic one word version.

[hongkong](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hongkong) has been remapped into [hong-kong](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hong-kong) and synonymised.

Comment: Definitely going to defer to Semaphore's expertise on this one.